# Responsive with flexbox

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a responsive page using flexbox. So far i was able to center my page just fine but right now is not responsive. When i reduce my width my box that contains inside-box,texto and buttons  doesn't shrink to fit the page.

Im using rem and % a lot i just don't know what im missing.

https://jsfiddle.net/daezfo8w/

```
html{
    height: 100%; 
 }

 body{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     height: 100vh;
     color: #fff;
     font-family: 'Roboto' , sans-serif;
     background: linear-gradient(to top, #36513b, #799d7e);
     line-height: 1.4rem;
 }



.inside-box{
    background: #d4d6d8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1.5px 0 0 rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.1);
    width: 65rem;
    height: 55rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Your .inside-box has a fixed width and can therefore not shrink. Try adding max-width: 100%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First don´t use display:flex in body

```
 body{

 height: 100vh;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Roboto' , sans-serif;
 background: linear-gradient(to top, #36513b, #799d7e);
 line-height: 1.4rem;
 }
```

Second for responsive sites use % for widths in layers, use rems for text, paddings etc because rem is something with a determinate with and can be higher than the width of the viewport... so change this CSS

```
.inside-box{
background: #d4d6d8;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 1.5px 0 0 rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.1);
width:100%;
height: 55rem;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MAXXALANDER/1ak7s9yf/4/

Comment: When i do this inside-box is not centered anymore, so i just added justify-content: center;  align-items: center; text-align: center;, but inside-box is not centered anymore. https://jsfiddle.net/3qfz0ymn/

Comment: If I am undestranding you need this https://jsfiddle.net/MAXXALANDER/3Lvw6j8o/2/

Comment: .inside-box h1,
.inside-box h2,
.inside-box p{
  text-align:center;
}

Comment: I mean inside-box now aligns horizontally but no vertically, so tried add   align-items: center; but inside-box stays fixed on the top of the page

Comment: Sorry, I don´t now if I am undestanding you, do you want to do this? https://jsfiddle.net/MAXXALANDER/3Lvw6j8o/11/

Comment: #############
#     1              #
#  $$$$$$       #
#  $ 2    $        #
#  $      $        #
#  $$$$$$       #
#                #
#                #
#############
i want the inside-box to be centered and with the grey color inside it. Outside theres is another color the linear-gradient one.
With your code everything becames grey because of height:1200px, and also is not responsive to use px right?